# Set datagrid colume to array variable

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagrid with 5 columes. I also have 5 array variables, Im looking to put Row 1----Columne 1 value into a[0], Columne 2 value into b[0]... etc is this possible?

cheers! ty!

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the DataGrid's DataSource to the array. See this [MS-KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315784) for examples.